# Error when trying to access binance API: 'Binance' object has no attribute 'binance_keys'

Tags: python, bots, binance

Please assist, i am coding a bot working with Binance and get the error stated when i try access the API to make a purchase. the API key is stored in a txt file:

line 332, in signRequest
signature = hmac.new(self.binance_keys['secret_key'].encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
AttributeError: 'Binance' object has no attribute 'binance_keys'

Code line 332:

```
import requests 
import json
import decimal
import hmac
import time
import pandas as pd
import hashlib
from decimal import Decimal

request_delay = 1000

class Binance:

    ORDER_STATUS_NEW = 'NEW'
    ORDER_STATUS_PARTIALLY_FILLED = 'PARTIALLY_FILLED'
    ORDER_STATUS_FILLED = 'FILLED'
    ORDER_STATUS_CANCELED = 'CANCELED'
    ORDER_STATUS_PENDING_CANCEL = 'PENDING_CANCEL'
    ORDER_STATUS_REJECTED = 'REJECTED'
    ORDER_STATUS_EXPIRED = 'EXPIRED'

    SIDE_BUY = 'BUY'
    SIDE_SELL = 'SELL'

    ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT = 'LIMIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_MARKET = 'MARKET'
    ORDER_TYPE_STOP_LOSS = 'STOP_LOSS'
    ORDER_TYPE_STOP_LOSS_LIMIT = 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_TAKE_PROFIT = 'TAKE_PROFIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT = 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT_MAKER = 'LIMIT_MAKER'

    KLINE_INTERVALS = ['1m', '3m', '5m', '15m', '30m', '1h', '2h', '4h', '6h', '8h', '12h', '1d', '3d', '1w', '1M']

    def __init__(self, filename=None):

        self.base = 'https://api.binance.com'

        self.endpoints = {
            "order": '/api/v3/order',
            "testOrder": '/api/v3/order/test',
            "allOrders": '/api/v3/allOrders',
            "klines": '/api/v3/klines',
            "exchangeInfo": '/api/v3/exchangeInfo',
            "24hrTicker" : '/api/v3/ticker/24hr',
            "averagePrice" : '/api/v3/avgPrice',
            "orderBook" : '/api/v3/depth',
            "account" : '/api/v3/account'
        }
        self.account_access = False

        if filename == None:
            return
    
        f = open(filename, "r")
        contents = []
        if f.mode == 'r':
            contents = f.read().split('\n')

        self.binance_keys = dict(api_key = contents[0], secret_key=contents[1])

        self.headers = {"X-MBX-APIKEY": self.binance_keys['api_key']}

        self.account_access = True
    
    def _get(self, url, params=None, headers=None) -> dict:
        """ Makes a Get Request """
        try: 
            response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            data['url'] = url
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception occured when trying to access "+url)
            print(e)
            data = {'code': '-1', 'url':url, 'msg': e}
        return data

    def _post(self, url, params=None, headers=None) -> dict:
        """ Makes a Post Request """
        try: 
            response = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            data['url'] = url
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception occured when trying to access "+url)
            print(e)
            data = {'code': '-1', 'url':url, 'msg': e}
        return data

    def GetTradingSymbols(self, quoteAssets:list=None):
        ''' Gets All symbols which are tradable (currently) '''
        url = self.base + self.endpoints["exchangeInfo"]
        data = self._get(url)
        if data.__contains__('code'):
            return []

        symbols_list = []
        for pair in data['symbols']:
            if pair['status'] == 'TRADING':
                if quoteAssets != None and pair['quoteAsset'] in quoteAssets:
                    symbols_list.append(pair['symbol'])

        return symbols_list

    def GetSymbolDataOfSymbols(self, symbols:list=None):
        ''' Gets All symbols which are tradable (currently) '''
        url = self.base + self.endpoints["exchangeInfo"]
        data = self._get(url)
        if data.__contains__('code'):
            return []

        symbols_list = []

        for pair in data['symbols']:
            if pair['status'] == 'TRADING':
                if symbols != None and pair['symbol'] in symbols:
                    symbols_list.append(pair)

        return symbols_list

    def GetSymbolKlinesExtra(self, symbol:str, interval:str, limit:int=1000, end_time=False):
        # Basicall, we will be calling the GetSymbolKlines as many times as we need 
        # in order to get all the historical data required (based on the limit parameter)
        # and we'll be merging the results into one long dataframe.

        repeat_rounds = 0
        if limit > 1000:
            repeat_rounds = int(limit/1000)
        initial_limit = limit % 1000
        if initial_limit == 0:
            initial_limit = 1000
        # First, we get the last initial_limit candles, starting at end_time and going
        # backwards (or starting in the present moment, if end_time is False)
        df = self.GetSymbolKlines(symbol, interval, limit=initial_limit, end_time=end_time)
        while repeat_rounds > 0:
            # Then, for every other 1000 candles, we get them, but starting at the beginning
            # of the previously received candles.
            df2 = self.GetSymbolKlines(symbol, interval, limit=1000, end_time=df['time'][0])
            df = df2.append(df, ignore_index = True)
            repeat_rounds = repeat_rounds - 1
        
        return df

    def GetAccountData(self) -> dict:
        """ Gets Balances & Account Data """

        url = self.base + self.endpoints["account"]
        
        params = {
        'recvWindow': 6000,
        'timestamp': int(round(time.time()*1000)) + request_delay
        }
        self.signRequest(params)
        
        return self._get(url, params, self.headers)

    def Get24hrTicker(self, symbol:str):
        url = self.base + self.endpoints['24hrTicker'] + "?symbol="+symbol
        return self._get(url)

    def GetSymbolKlines(self, symbol:str, interval:str, limit:int=1000, end_time=False):
        ''' 
        Gets trading data for one symbol 
        
        Parameters
        --
            symbol str:        The symbol for which to get the trading data

            interval str:      The interval on which to get the trading data
                minutes      '1m' '3m' '5m' '15m' '30m'
                hours        '1h' '2h' '4h' '6h' '8h' '12h'
                days         '1d' '3d'
                weeks        '1w'
                months       '1M;
        '''

        if limit > 1000:
            return self.GetSymbolKlinesExtra(symbol, interval, limit, end_time)
        
        params = '?&symbol='+symbol+'&interval='+interval+'&limit='+str(limit)
        if end_time:
            params = params + '&endTime=' + str(int(end_time))

        url = self.base + self.endpoints['klines'] + params

        # download data
        data = requests.get(url)
        dictionary = json.loads(data.text)

        # put in dataframe and clean-up
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
        df = df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)

        # rename columns
        col_names = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        df.columns = col_names

        # transform values from strings to floats
        for col in col_names:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(float)

        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] * 1000000, infer_datetime_format=True)

        return df
    
    def PlaceOrderFromDict(self, params, test:bool=False):
        """ Places order from params dict """

        params['recvWindow'] = 5000
        params['timestamp'] = int(round(time.time()*1000)) + request_delay
        
        self.signRequest(params)
        url = ''
        if test: 
            url = self.base + self.endpoints['testOrder']
        else:
            url = self.base + self.endpoints['order']
        return self._post(url, params, self.headers)

    def PlaceOrder(self, symbol:str, side:str, type:str, quantity:float=0, price:float=0, test:bool=True):
        '''
        Places an order on Binance
        Parameters
        --
            symbol str:        The symbol for which to get the trading data
            side str:          The side of the order 'BUY' or 'SELL'
            type str:          The type, 'LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS'
            quantity float:    .....

        '''

        params = {
            'symbol': symbol,
            'side': side,           # BUY or SELL
            'type': type,               # MARKET, LIMIT, STOP LOSS etc
            'quoteOrderQty': quantity,
            'recvWindow': 5000,
            'timestamp': int(round(time.time()*1000)) + request_delay
        }

        if type != 'MARKET':
            params['timeInForce'] = 'GTC'
            params['price'] = Binance.floatToString(price)

        self.signRequest(params)

        url = ''
        if test: 
            url = self.base + self.endpoints['testOrder']
        else:
            url = self.base + self.endpoints['order']

        return self._post(url, params=params, headers=self.headers)

    def CancelOrder(self, symbol:str, orderId:str):
        '''
            Cancels the order on a symbol based on orderId
        '''

        params = {
            'symbol': symbol,
            'orderId' : orderId,
            'recvWindow': 5000,
            'timestamp': int(round(time.time()*1000)) + request_delay
        }

        self.signRequest(params)

        url = self.base + self.endpoints['order']

        try: 
            response = requests.delete(url, params=params, headers=self.headers)
            data = response.text
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception occured when trying to cancel order on "+url)
            print(e)
            data = {'code': '-1', 'msg':e}
        
        return json.loads(data)

    def GetOrderInfo(self, symbol:str, orderId:str):
        '''
            Gets info about an order on a symbol based on orderId
        '''

        params = {
            'symbol': symbol,
            'origClientOrderId' : orderId,
            'recvWindow': 5000,
            'timestamp': int(round(time.time()*1000)) + request_delay
        }

        self.signRequest(params)

        url = self.base + self.endpoints['order']

        return self._get(url, params=params, headers=self.headers)

    def GetAllOrderInfo(self, symbol:str):
        '''
            Gets info about all order on a symbol
        '''

        params = {
            'symbol': symbol,
            'timestamp': int(round(time.time()*1000)) + request_delay
        }

        self.signRequest(params)

        url = self.base + self.endpoints['allOrders']

        try: 
            response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=self.headers)
            data = response.text
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception occured when trying to get info on all orders on "+url)
            print(e)
            data = {'code': '-1', 'msg':e}

        return json.loads(data)

    def signRequest(self, params:dict):
        ''' Signs the request to the Binance API '''

        query_string = '&'.join(["{}={}".format(d, params[d]) for d in params])
        signature = hmac.new(self.binance_keys['secret_key'].encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
        params['signature'] = signature.hexdigest()
    
    @classmethod
    def floatToString(cls, f:float):
        ''' Converts the given float to a string,
        without resorting to the scientific notation '''

        ctx = decimal.Context()
        ctx.prec = 12
        d1 = ctx.create_decimal(repr(f))
        return format(d1, 'f')

    @classmethod
    def get10Factor(cls, num):
        """ Returns the number of 0s before the first non-0 digit of a number 
        (if |num| is < than 1) or negative the number of digits between the first 
        integer digit and the last, (if |num| >= 1) 
        
        get10Factor(0.00000164763) = 6
        get10Factor(1600623.3) = -6
        """
        p = 0
        for i in range(-20, 20):
            if num == num % 10**i:
                p = -(i - 1)
                break
        return p

    @classmethod
    def RoundToValidPrice(cls, symbol_data, desired_price, round_up:bool=False) -> Decimal:
        """ Returns the minimum quantity of a symbol we can buy,
        closest to desiredPrice """
        
        pr_filter = {}
        
        for fil in symbol_data["filters"]:
            if fil["filterType"] == "PRICE_FILTER":
                pr_filter = fil
                break
        
        if not pr_filter.keys().__contains__("tickSize"):
            raise Exception("Couldn't find tickSize or PRICE_FILTER in symbol_data.")
            return

        round_off_number = int(cls.get10Factor((float(pr_filter["tickSize"]))))

        number = round(Decimal(desired_price), round_off_number)
        if round_up:
            number = number + Decimal(pr_filter["tickSize"])

        return number

    @classmethod
    def RoundToValidQuantity(cls, symbol_data, desired_quantity, round_up:bool=False) -> Decimal:
        """ Returns the minimum quantity of a symbol we can buy,
        closest to desiredPrice """
        
        lot_filter = {}
        
        for fil in symbol_data["filters"]:
            if fil["filterType"] == "LOT_SIZE":
                lot_filter = fil
                break
        
        if not lot_filter.keys().__contains__("stepSize"):
            raise Exception("Couldn't find stepSize or PRICE_FILTER in symbol_data.")
            return

        round_off_number = int(cls.get10Factor((float(lot_filter["stepSize"]))))

        number = round(Decimal(desired_quantity), round_off_number)
        if round_up:
            number = number + Decimal(lot_filter["stepSize"])

        return number


def Main():

    symbol = 'NEOBTC'
    client_id = '73a40bae-61c7-11ea-8e67-f40f241d61b4'
    exchange = Binance('credentials.txt')

    d = exchange.GetOrderInfo(symbol, client_id)
    print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: add full code pelase

Comment: added code, please assist. I cant figure it out, some investigations seemed to lead to having to reinstall python-binance but that didnt work

Comment: We don't need more code, we need less.  Gradually take things out until the problem goes away.  Then you will know that the last thing you took out was problematic.  Try to construct a [mcve] and if you can and you are still puzzled, post it here.  Or alternately, debug it in a debugger, or even put in `print` statements to check that the `binance_keys` attribute is present in the `Binance` object at construction and at various points after that.

Comment: thanks , previous poster said to add more code, so I did... it happens in line 332, when I have selected to make a buy on the  position. this is the line: signature = hmac.new(self.binance_keys['secret_key'].encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
  params['signature'] = signature.hexdigest(), then i get the error. where would i put a print statment in?

Comment: Start with one right after the construction of the Binance object in Main.  If the binance_keys are not there at that point, you know something went wrong in the constructor and you can stick some more in there to see if control actually reached the point where you create that attribute.  If the binance_keys are there in Main after construction, then put print statements in GetOrderInfo and signRequest.